# Incorrect result of ParameterMixtureDistribution

Tags: simplifying-expressions, bugs, probability-or-statistics

Let us consider in 13.1 on Windows 10

```
distr = ParameterMixtureDistribution[BinomialDistribution[n + 1, p], 
n \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]]];
PDF[distr, t];
FullSimplify[%, Assumptions ->  t >= 0 && t \[Element] Integers && p > 0 && p < 1 && \[Lambda] > 0]
```

> `Piecewise[{{ComplexInfinity, t <= 1}}, (p^t*\[Lambda]^(-1 + t)*(t + \[Lambda] - p*\[Lambda]))/(E^(p*\[Lambda])*t!)]`

The above result is clearly incorrect in view of

```
Sum[(E^(-p \[Lambda]) p^t \[Lambda]^(-1 + t) (t + \[Lambda] - p *\[Lambda]))/ t!,
{t, 2, Infinity}, Assumptions -> p > 0 && p < 1 && \[Lambda] > 0]
```

> `E^(-p \[Lambda]) (-1 + E^(p \[Lambda]) - p \[Lambda] + p^2 \[Lambda])`

instead of `1`.

Is it a bug or I don't understand something? If we face with a bug, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

distr = ParameterMixtureDistribution[
   BinomialDistribution[n + 1, p],
   n \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[λ]];

assume = DistributionParameterAssumptions[distr]

(* 0 <= p <= 1 && λ > 0 *)

PDF[distr, t]
```

[image]

```
pdf0 = PDF[distr, 0]

(* -E^(-p λ) (-1 + p) *)

pdf1 = PDF[distr, 1]

(* E^(-p λ) p (1 + λ - p λ) *)

pdft = Assuming[t > 1 && Element[t, Integers], 
  PDF[distr, t] // FullSimplify]

(* (E^(-p λ) p^t λ^(-1 + t) (t + λ - p λ))/t! *)

pdf0 + pdf1 + Sum[pdft, {t, 2, Infinity}] // Simplify

(* 1 *)
```

**EDIT:**

```
(pdft /. t -> 1) == pdf1

(* True *)

(pdft /. t -> 0) == pdf0 // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Consequently,

```
pdf = pdft

(* (E^(-p λ) p^t λ^(-1 + t) (t + λ - p λ))/t! *)
```

The mean is

```
μ = Sum[t*pdf, {t, 0, Infinity}] // Simplify

(* p (1 + λ) *)
```

The variance is

```
var = Sum[(t - μ)^2*pdf, {t, 0, Infinity}] // Simplify

(* p (1 - p + λ) *)
```

Comment: This is it. Works in 13.1 on Windows 10 too. Therefore, we face with a bug in `FullSimplify`, not in `ParameterMixtureDistribution`.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug in `FullSimplify`. `FullSimplify` did what you asked. The problem is that with the definition of the `PDF` the values for `t==0` and `t==1` are only defined in the limit. Once you have the simplified `pdf`, use it to redefine the distribution, i.e., `distr2 = ProbabilityDistribution[pdf, {t, 0, Infinity, 1}, Assumptions -> assume];`

Answer (score 5):

I agree the that resulting `Piecewise` function is wrong if for no other reason than `ComplexInfinity` is assigned when `t = 0`.

If you want a `Piecewise` function that works, the following is a workaround:

```
distr = ParameterMixtureDistribution[BinomialDistribution[n + 1, p], 
   n \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[λ], Assumptions -> 0 < p < 1 && λ > 0];
PDF[distr, t];
temp = FullSimplify[%, Assumptions -> t >= 0 && t ∈ Integers && p > 0 && p < 1 && λ > 0][[2]];
pmf = Piecewise[{{temp, t ∈ NonNegativeIntegers}}, 0]
```

[image: pmf for ParameterMixtureDistribution]

This sums to 1:

```
Sum[pmf, {t, 0, ∞}]
(* 1 *)
```

Comment: Than you for your interest to the question. Unfortunately, this is not any workaround. Let us call things by their proper names.  You choose from `Piecewise[{{ComplexInfinity, t <= 1}}, (p^t*\[Lambda]^(-1 + t)*(t + \[Lambda] - p*\[Lambda]))/(E^(p*\[Lambda])*t!)]` its second part, i.e.  `(p^t*\[Lambda]^(-1 + t)*(t + \[Lambda] - p*\[Lambda]))/(E^(p*\[Lambda])*t!)` and then make its unwarranted and ungrounded  extension on all the `PositiveIntegers`. The relation  `Sum[pmf, {t, 0, ∞}]==1` proves nothing: there is a lot ow ways to extend `temp` on `PositiveIntegers` to make the sum  equal to `1`.

Comment: Thank you for your frank response.  I used `NonNegativeIntegers` and not `PositiveIntegers`.  Where do you see `PositiveIntegers`?  (I agree that just because the sum of the resulting probabilities is 1 doesn't confirm that it is the correct answer.  But that is a necessary condition.)

Comment: `n+1` ,where `n \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]]` ,  cannot take `0`.

Comment: True.  But the pdf is about $t$ (the number of successes) and not $n+1$ (the number of trials).

Comment: JimB (@ does not work.) : You are right. BTW, `ParameterMixtureDistribution[BinomialDistribution[n , p], n \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]]]` is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running 11.3 on Windows, and I noticed that you summed only from two to infinity, rather than from zero.

```
Sum[(E^(-p \[Lambda]) p^
     t \[Lambda]^(-1 + t) (t + \[Lambda] - p*\[Lambda]))/t!, {t, 0, 
  Infinity}, Assumptions -> p > 0 && p < 1 && \[Lambda] > 0]
```

Returns 1.